# Vscode: error TS2307: Cannot find module 'vscode'

Tags: npm, visual-studio-code

When compiling VSCode extension then typescript persistently complained

> error TS2307: Cannot find module 'vscode'.

Installation `npm install vscode` or magic links never helped.

Strace provided:

```
stat("/home/work/mymodule/src/node_modules", 0x7ffe73f2d460) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/home/work/mymodule/node_modules", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0775, st_size=4096, ...}) = 0
stat("/home/work/mymodule/node_modules/vscode", 0x7ffe73f2d200) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/home/work/mymodule/node_modules", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0775, st_size=4096, ...}) = 0
stat("/home/work/mymodule/node_modules/vscode.ts", 0x7ffe73f2d040) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/home/work/mymodule/node_modules/vscode.tsx", 0x7ffe73f2d040) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/home/work/mymodule/node_modules/vscode.d.ts", 0x7ffe73f2d040) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/home/work/mymodule/node_modules/vscode", 0x7ffe73f2d230) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/home/work/mymodule/node_modules/@types", 0x7ffe73f2d460) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/home/tma/work/qore/node_modules", 0x7ffe73f2d460) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/home/tma/work/node_modules", 0x7ffe73f2d460) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/home/tma/node_modules", 0x7ffe73f2d460) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/home/node_modules", 0x7ffe73f2d460) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/node_modules", 0x7ffe73f2d460)   = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/home/work/mymodule/src/node_modules", 0x7ffe73f2d460) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/home/work/mymodule/node_modules", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0775, st_size=4096, ...}) = 0
stat("/home/work/mymodule/node_modules/vscode", 0x7ffe73f2d200) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/home/work/mymodule/node_modules", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0775, st_size=4096, ...}) = 0
stat("/home/work/mymodule/node_modules/vscode.js", 0x7ffe73f2d040) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/home/work/mymodule/node_modules/vscode.jsx", 0x7ffe73f2d040) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/home/work/mymodule/node_modules/vscode", 0x7ffe73f2d230) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
```

How to proceed?

Comment: I had the same problem. I deleted the node_modules and installed it again and it worked like charm.

Answer (score 32):

#### The solution

Run `npm install` to fix the issue.

#### Why?

Because there is "post install" script (`node ./node_modules/vscode/bin/install`) which fetch a **vscode.d.ts** according to the engine you're using in your project.

> Detected VS Code engine version: ^1.6.0
> Found minimal version that qualifies engine range: 1.6.0
> Fetching vscode.d.ts from: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Microsoft/vscode/e52fb0bc87e6f5c8f144e172639891d8d8c9aa55/src/vs/vscode.d.ts
> vscode.d.ts successfully installed!

[source](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/2810#issuecomment-181724735)

Comment: I had already run `npm install` but running it again did the trick

Comment: Running npm post install does all that, but when it actually runs the node program above, it goes into this error "Error installing vscode.d.ts: Missing VSCode engine declaration in package.json."
Went back and ran yo code again (since I had permission error) and it worked.
[this link](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-extension-vscode/issues/143#issuecomment-478565843) helped understanding the cause of the issue.

Answer (score 4):

I suggest that you close and open VS Code

Comment: I had randomly this issue and restart worked just fine.

Comment: haha never thought this would work

Answer (score 1):

The solution is a link pointing to `vscode.d.ts` from `node_modules` directory.

```
ln -s /home/work/mymodule/node_modules/vscode.d.ts /usr/share/code/resources/app/out/vs/vscode.d.ts
```

Answer (score 0):

Update your `Package.json` `"scripts"` section to be:

```
"compile": "tsc -watch -p ./",
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the reason is: can't load a module with a long path on Windows.
Relate issue link: https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/1990

So, after I upgrade nodejs v14.x to v15.x, the issue was gone.

Answer (score 0):

If you get this error when trying to create a `webview` for a vsCode extension, check that you are doing it under the `client` folder and no the `server` folder