# How to instantiate objects of 'vscode module' used classes from unit tests. Error: Cannot find module 'vscode'

Tags: typescript, unit-testing, visual-studio-code, mocha.js, vscode-extensions

I am writing extension for vscode. Here this instantiation failes only at test files. This didn't resolve by npm-install ( like in  [Vscode: error TS2307: Cannot find module 'vscode'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49383342/vscode-error-ts2307-cannot-find-module-vscode) )

class:

```
import * as vscode from 'vscode';

export class PopupMessage {
    public ShowInfoMessage(message: string) {
        vscode.window.showInformationMessage(message);
    }
}
```

test class :

```
import { expect } from 'chai';
import * as vscode from 'vscode';
import { PopupMessage } from '../../popupMessage';

const popupMessage: PopupMessage = new PopopMessage(); // error at npm run test

describe('tests for popupMessage', () => {

    it('unit tests for popupMessage.ShowInfoMessage()', () => {
          ...
    });

});
```

Same type (PopupMessage) object can be used in non-test files with no errors.
Any suggestions to proceed?

Thanks in advance.