# VSCode Error: The terminal process "node.exe '-e' - terminated with exit code: 1

Tags: terraform, vscode-extensions, terraform-provider-azure

When trying to utilise the Azure Terraform extension to upload my library of labs I would get the following error.

```
The terminal process "node.exe '-e', 'require('c:\\Users\\*****\\.vscode\\extensions\\ms-vscode.azure-account-0.11.4\\dist\\cloudConsoleLauncher').main()'" terminated with exit code: 1.

OS: Windows Server 2019 Standard (NT x64 10.0.17763)
VSCode Version: 1.78.0
```

Comment: I wonder if this message is relevant "First launch of Cloud Shell in a directory requires setup in the web application (https://shell.azure.com)." Also the same message offers a Help button that [directs me here](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/supporting/troubleshoot-terminal-launch)

Comment: When I try to launch the terminal I briefly see this message:

`Error: Cannot find module 'vscode'
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: [
    'c:\\Users\\****\\.vscode\\extensions\\ms-vscode.azure-account-0.11.4\\dist\\cloudConsoleLauncher.js',
    'C:\\Users\\****\\kind-glacier\\[eval]'
  ]` , maybe related to [this answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49383342/vscode-error-ts2307-cannot-find-module-vscode)

Answer (score 1):

I have resolve this from rectifying two issues.

1. I am using Windows Server so wsl is not installed to the machine. Test this by running the PowerShell command `wslconfig.exe /l` and if it doesn't know the cmlet you need to set this up on Windows Server following the [link here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install-on-server)

Then you need to install a Linux distribution - I chose Debian it works fine

2. Install the Microsoft WSL extension to VSCode and then reboot

Other things to check

- Have you installed [Node](https://nodejs.org/en)?
- Have you installed [Git](https://git-scm.com/downloads)?

But yes, this looks like the main issue is not having a WSL library installed as it does not come out of the box with Windows Server.